# How do I solve the "undefined variable" error on laravel when I go to my show view?

Tags: laravel

How do I solve the "undefined variable" error on laravel when I go to my show view?

When I go to my show view URL I receive an error saying "Undefined variable: questionnaire".

My routes file:

```
<?php
/*
This is the file in which the rules for how users will use the application are kept
*/

Route::get('/',function() {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/questionnaires/', 'QuestionnairesController@show');

Route::resource('/questionnaires', 'QuestionnairesController');

Route::resource('/questions', 'QuestionsController');

Route::resource('/answers', 'AnswersController');

Route::post('/questionnaires/create', 'QuestionnairesController@create');
```

My show view:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', $questionnaire->title)

@section('content')
    @foreach($questionnaires as $questionnaire)
        <h1>{{ $questionnaire->title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ $questionnaire->description }}</p>
        <p>{{ $questionnaire->ethics }}</p>

        <a href="{{ route('questionnaires.index') }}" class="btn btn-info">Back to your questionnaires</a>
        <a href="{{ route('questionnaires.edit') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>

        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['questionnaires.destroy', $questionnaire->id]]) !!}
            {!! Form::submit('Delete questionnaire', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    @endforeach

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

When returning a view, do not forget to pass `$questionnaires` to it:

```
return view('some.view', compact('questionnaires'));
```

Also, always check $questionnaires for `null` or `empty`:

```
@if(is_null($questionnaires))
    //do foreach...

@if(!empty($questionnaires))
    //do foreach...
```

Comment: I have done the first thing, I have passed $questionnaires with it

Comment: What about checking for `null`? Sometimes queries just return null (do not find any data).

Comment: If by that you mean wrap the `@foreach` that is in the `show` view inside the `@if(is_null($questionnaires))` and `@endif`, then yeah I've done that as well and no change

Comment: I wonder why didn't you use `return view` code from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

In the controller responsible for presenting the questionnaire, you need to pass in the variable.

```
return view('questionnaire', [
    'questionnaire' => $questionnaire,
]);
```

If you don't do this, the blade templates have no idea what that variable is.

Comment: Correction, this has worked now. but only when I have `@if(!empty($questionnaires))` wrapping around the `@foreach` in the `show` view

Answer (score 0):

your problem is here:

```
@section('title', $questionnaire->title)
```

You already passed $questionnaires to your view. But not $questionnaire.

Answer (score 0):

return both variable in view

```
return view('some.view', compact('questionnaire', 'questionnaires'));
```

after check variable in controller

```
@if(isset($questionnaire->title))
```

and check array

```
$questionnaire_array= array_filter($questionnaires);
@if(!empty($questionnaire_array))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@if($questionnaires->count())
@foreach($questionaires as $questionaire)
@section('title', $questionnaire->title)
@section('content')


<h1>{{ $questionnaire->title }}</h1>

<p>{{ $questionnaire->description }}</p>

<p>{{ $questionnaire->ethics }}</p>

   <a href="{{ route('questionnaires.index') }}" class="btn btn-info">Back to your questionnaires</a>
    `<a href="{{ route('questionnaires.edit') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>`

    `{!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['questionnaires.destroy', $questionnaire->id]]) !!}`
        `{!! Form::submit('Delete questionnaire', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}`
   `{!! Form::close() !!}`
@endsection
@endforeach
@endif
```